# Spring + Hibernate Search dynamic configuraion

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm currently trying to configure hibernate search via spring across 3 machines for the purpose of using a JMS distributed index. Due to the way we deploy our software I have to use the same configuration across all three machines but I need a way to set one of them to be the JMS Master.

Currently hibernate is being configured via Spring using the following bean declaration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
id="productSessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="productDataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="builderInterceptor"/>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
            <entry key="save" value-ref="saveEventListener"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

On one of the three machines I need to set the property hibernate.search.default.directory_provider to filesystem-master and on the other two I need to set it to filesystem-slave.

I have the ability to set flags on the individual machines to identify which machine should be the master but due to all the configuration being XML I dont have any ability to add logic to set the parameters correctly.

Is there an way to set this parameter programmatically while leaving the rest of the configuration alone?

Thanks!

Comment: I've always thought that the master/slave configuration is a pain! I like the sound of the JGroups auto-election of the master :)

Answer (score 0):

A programmatic way is generally possible, but I am not sure exactly how you do that in Spring. Instead of putting your properties into a config file you would have to build the properties dynamically (or at least partly dynamically) and pass it to *AnnotationSessionFactoryBean*. If I am not mistaken there are hooks in the Spring SPI which should allow you to do that, eg *BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor*.

The other approach would be to write your own *DirectoryProvider*. Have a look at *org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSMasterDirectoryProvider* and *org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSSlaveDirectoryProvider* and write a provider which can act as slave or master depending on the flag you can read on the machine.